# how to limit widget wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Regards. I work on a theme of wordpress and I have footer area.I am trying to limit the widget to 3 widget I only have 3 spots in my  theme so I searched and no answer in this at any site.

I am using this code to display the footer widget

```
if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')|| !dynamic_sidebar('footer')) :
 echo "<p> No Widget Here </p>";
endif ;
```

so here no limit for widget I wanna limit it to 3 spots
my footer looks like :

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row s">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-col pull-0">
        <h6 class="heading7 heading72">Social Media</h6>
        <ul class="footer-social ">
        <?php global $any_thing; ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $any_thing['social3'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-instagram social-icon instagram-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $any_thing['social2'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook social-icon facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $any_thing['social4'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter social-icon twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $any_thing['social1'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus social-icon google" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
      
<?php
if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')|| !dynamic_sidebar('footer')) :
?>
<p>No Wedgit Here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try limit the number of widgets in such way.

```
$sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
$count_sidebar_widgets = count( $sidebars['footer'] );
$limit_widgets = 3;

if ( $count_sidebar_widgets <= $limit_widgets ) {
    dynamic_sidebar('footer');
} else {
    ?>
    <p>Over the allowed widget limit</p>
    <?php
}
```